# Cause of google vision API HTTP Forbidden error? Ruby (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I have been trying to get the google vision API to work in my rails application but keep getting a **Net::HTTPForbidden** response.  I'm not really sure what is causing it since everything I have seems to be setup properly, I've tried generating new keys and still get the same error, any help would be appreciated.  I replaced my API key with 'XXXXX_MY_API_KEY_XXXXX' in this post for obvious reasons, so that is not the issue, also have tried directly pasting in an image url in place of the 'img_url' so I don't think that that is related to the issue either.

```
 require 'net/http'
  require 'uri'
  require 'json'

def transcribe(img_url)

    uri = URI.parse('https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=' + 'XXXXX_MY_API_KEY_XXXXX')
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
    request.content_type = 'application/json'
    request.body = JSON.dump(
      'requests' => [
        {
          'image' => {
            'source' => {
              'imageUri' => img_url
            }
          },
          'features' => [
            {
              'type' => 'TEXT_DETECTION',
              'maxResults' => 1,
              'model' => 'builtin/latest'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    )

    req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https'
    }

    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end

    p response

    p response.code
    p response.body 
end
```

Comment: Is there any error message with that Forbidden? Is img_url something in your GCS bucket or a publicly accessible http/https image?

Comment: All I get is the http forbidden, no other info, it looks like this **'#<Net::HTTPForbidden:0x00007fd331c60cd0>'**
.  The img_url is just a string containing the url of a publicly available image, I tried using some random ones off the web and get the same error every time, cant seem to figure out whats going wrong.

Comment: It seems like the error message is being swallowed up by net/http. Can you double-check that the API is enabled? Also check there are any restrictions on the API key (make sure it is allowed to call Vision API). Maybe try sending the image in as bytes or a public gcs image too.

Comment: Have you tried out the client library? https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-ruby

Comment: Tried using gcs and b64 images but get the same result.  The api key is unrestricted so it should be able to access any cloud service api, and I have tried re-generating new keys.  I originally started with the client library but need to use an api key rather than the service account setup, but I was still getting similar issues with the client library before I switched.

Comment: What is the error message you get with the client library? The error message should help narrow down why there is a Forbidden.

Comment: The issue was an auth error which had to do with the 2-way authentication for service accounts.  Because I am running from local host I can't properly set up the API to work with a service account and need to use the API key instead.

Comment: Not sure if this helps at all but when I switch from TEXT_DETECTION to LABEL_DETECTION I get the same error (HTTPForbidden), and when I switch to  DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION I get a HTTPBadRequest 'The request cannot be completed based on your current cloud settings' error.  I double checked my keys restrictions and there were none, after restricting the key to to google cloud api only I continued to get the same errors.

Comment: Service account should still work from localhost. That is probably a separate question though. I'm guessing you have to either enable the api or turn on billing. Can you try this example with curl: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-cli  Eliminate ruby from what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after hours of messing around with this I finally figured out the issue.  When you first try to use the api they will return a link to you that you have to visit to activate the specific API (vision in my case), I could not find this page through the ui on the google cloud control panel, only through the link.  Even though the API key was active and unrestricted with billing setup it would not function without activating the specific API.  Because I had commented out the response code/body I was only getting the status code for my API call and was not seeing the rest of the response, preventing me from finding the proper activation link.

This was a massive lapse of judgement on my part, hopefully this will help anyone who runs into a similar issue or is looking to integrate google vision API into a rails app and stumbles upon this thread, the code shown above works totally fine and is a much simpler approach to using the API when compared to the client library, just make sure that you have the specific API that you want to use enabled.  Just because the API key is not restricted does not mean that you can simply use any of their APIs, I made sure to 'fix' (uncomment) the code I posted for anyone else who may find it useful.

Comment: Glad to hear you tracked down the issue.

Comment: Just to emphasize, most Google Cloud APIs need to be "enabled" before they can be called (for each Project that you use). Many should give you a link you can use to activate the API in the HTTP error response body, but if you don't want to go through the exercise of calling the API and copying the link from the response, you can activate APIs from the Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com). Choose "APIs and Services" from the left nav, click the "Enable APIs and Services" button at the top of that page, and search for the API you want to enable.